# Creating directory and extract BLOB inside there in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, blob

I am trying to extract BLOB into file in respected directory.
Here is my table looks like :

[image]

After executing the code it should create all 3 folders inside @outPutPath for each row from the table and create the files inside it.

I have working code for extracting the files (below code) but when I added two extra lines (add @folderName in @fPath) for creating directories its not working anymore. May be directory check if exist and create will be a good idea, not sure. If anyone can help with it?

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
drop table [dbo].[Document];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Document](
    [Doc_Num] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Folder_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Extension] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Doc_Content] [varbinary](max) NULL   
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Document] ON
GO

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
delete from [dbo].[Document] where Doc_Num in (1,3,4);


Insert into Document (Doc_Num,Folder_Name,Extension,FileName,Doc_Content)
select 2 as Doc_Num,'Test2','JPG' AS Extension,'TestImage.jpg' as FileName,*
from openrowset(bulk 'C:\temp\BICH\TestBLOB\Import\TestImage.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB)
as X
GO
Insert into Document (Doc_Num,Folder_Name,Extension,FileName,Doc_Content)
select 5 as Doc_Num,'Test5','JPG' AS Extension,'Angle2.png' as FileName,*
from openrowset(bulk 'C:\temp\BICH\TestBLOB\Import\Angle2.png', SINGLE_BLOB)
as X
GO
Insert into Document (Doc_Num,Folder_Name,Extension,FileName,Doc_Content)
select 6 as Doc_Num,'Test6','JPG' AS Extension,'iLoveTrD.png' as FileName,*
from openrowset(bulk 'C:\temp\BICH\TestBLOB\Import\iLoveTrD.png', SINGLE_BLOB)
as X
GO

--  select * from [Document]


-------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @outPutPath varchar(50) = 'C:\temp\BICH\TestBLOB\Export'
, @i bigint
, @init int
, @data varbinary(max) 
, @fPath varchar(max)  
, @folderPath  varchar(max)
, @folderName varchar(max)

--Get Data into temp Table variable so that we can iterate over it 
DECLARE @Doctable TABLE (id int identity(1,1), [Doc_Num]  varchar(100) , [Folder_Name] varchar(100) ,
[FileName]  varchar(100), [Doc_Content] varBinary(max) )

INSERT INTO @Doctable([Doc_Num],[Folder_Name],[FileName],[Doc_Content])
Select [Doc_Num],[Folder_Name],[FileName],[Doc_Content] FROM  [dbo].[Document]

SELECT @i = COUNT(1) FROM @Doctable   

WHILE @i >= 1   

BEGIN    

SELECT 
    @data = [Doc_Content],
    @folderName = [Folder_Name],
    @fPath = @outPutPath + '\' + [Doc_Num] +'_' + [FileName],
--  @fPath = @outPutPath + '\' + @folderName + '\' + [Doc_Num] +'_' + [FileName],
    @folderPath = @outPutPath + '\' + @folderName
    
FROM @Doctable WHERE id = @i

--EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @folderPath; -- Creating sub-directory
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT; -- An instace created
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;  
EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open'; -- Calling a method
EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @data; -- Calling a method
EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2; -- Calling a method
EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close'; -- Calling a method
EXEC sp_OADestroy @init; -- Closed the resources
print 'Document Generated at - '+  @fPath   

--Reset the variables for next use
SELECT @data = NULL  
, @init = NULL
, @fPath = NULL  
, @folderPath = NULL
SET @i -= 1
END
```

I can add the error I am getting if I enable create directory lines enabled.

```
(3 rows affected)
Msg 22048, Level 15, State 0, Line 60
Error executing extended stored procedure: Invalid Parameter
Document Generated at - C:\temp\BICH\TestBLOB\Export\Test6\6_iLoveTrD.png
Msg 22048, Level 15, State 0, Line 60
Error executing extended stored procedure: Invalid Parameter
Document Generated at - C:\temp\BICH\TestBLOB\Export\Test5\5_Angle2.png
Msg 22048, Level 15, State 0, Line 60
Error executing extended stored procedure: Invalid Parameter
Document Generated at - C:\temp\BICH\TestBLOB\Export\Test2\2_TestImage.jpg

Completion time: 2023-03-03T10:57:59.0748541+01:00
```

Comment: Usage of the OLE automation procs is frowned upon, they're unreliable and lead to server instability. If you add error checking to all of the calls to the sp_OA methods do any of them return error states? Do you check any of them with calls to sp_OAGetErrorInfo?

Comment: I have added the error now.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like if your directory doesn't exist. Which method call actually fails?

Comment: You have two different path variables which doesn't use same folder names

Comment: I think I solved the issue. "xp_create_subdir doesn't accept varchar(max) data type."
after i changed it to varchar(4000), its working.

Comment: Consider using Powershell to do this, as `sp_OA` procedures are fraught with difficulty.